# Symfony3 fosuserbundle form for admin with group

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms

i use Symfony3.3 and want to make a form for the admin administration. The user should be have a group and the group sould have the roles for the backend access.
The form for groups (name and roles) i finished and the form for the admins (name, passwort...) is finish too.
The admin will be find and have the group. If i load the admin it have the arraycollection with the groups.

Here my classes
admin:

```
class Admin extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(name="idAdmin", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, options={"default":NULL})
     */
    protected $style;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AdminBundle\Entity\AdminGroup")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="admin_has_group",
     *     joinColumns={
     *         @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idAdmin", referencedColumnName="idAdmin")
     *     },
     *     inverseJoinColumns={
     *         @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idGroup", referencedColumnName="idGroup")
     *     }
     * )
     */
    protected $groups;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStyle()
    {
        return $this->style;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $style
     */
    public function setStyle($style)
    {
        $this->style = $style;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setGroups($groups)
    {

        $this->groups = $groups;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGroups()
    {
        return $this->groups;
    }
}
```

groups

```
class AdminGroup extends BaseGroup
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="idGroup", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Group constructor.
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param array  $roles
     */
    public function __construct($name = '', $roles = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $roles);
    }
}
```

form generation

```
$admin = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Admin::class)->find(1);
$admingroupList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(AdminGroup::class)->findAll();
$form  = $this->createFormBuilder($admin)
    ->add("username", TextType::class)
    ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, $passwordSettings)
    ->add(
        'groups', ChoiceType::class, [
        'required' => false,
        'multiple' => true,
        'choices'  => $admingroupList,
    ])
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Save'])->getForm()->createView();
```

save form

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    $user = $form->getData();

    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    ....
}
```

The first problem is that i have in the overview only display the id's in the select.
The second problem is that i submit the form (with selected groups) symfony crashed with the following message

> Call to a member function contains() on array

I try to convert the grouplist to an normal array they will be crashed at the save the data

> Expected argument of type "FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupInterface", "integer" given

I dont know that i sould do to make a simple symfony form with the admin data and group selection... i dont find any example for a form with fosuserbundle...

Have someone an idea what i can to without manipulate the fosuserbundle entites or the symfonycode?

If you need more source, tell me with part :)

---

Editing 10.12.17
I try to convert the ChoosenArray into this format

```
$list = [
'user' => 0,
'admin' => 1
];
```

but than it will be broken at

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

with the error:

> Expected argument of type "FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupInterface", "integer" given

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the data returned from

```
 $admingroupList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(AdminGroup::class)->findAll();
```

Will work as you want it too. `choices` wants something like this

```
'choices' => [
    'Admin' => 'admin',
    'User' => 'user'
]
```

Where the key of the array is the name the user sees, and the value of the array is the value used in the `<option>`.

You probably need to manipulate the `$admingroupList` array to mimic the demo array above. Or write your own query in the AdminGroup Repo to return a pre-formatted array for use with a Symfony form.

Comment: i try what you mean, the array was Displayname as Arraykey and option-value as Arrayvalue but than it will be crashed at
```
   $form->handleRequest($request);
```
because symfony try to give the numeric value to the method witch need a list of objects...

Comment: Update your answer

Comment: The answer is right there in the error. You’re giving it an integer. Why? It needs to be the name of the group. Eg ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: i want to assign the admin to a group... not role... and i dont make it it will be wring displayed in form

Comment: i try and get this error "Type error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in \vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 605"  (remember, it's the fosuserbundle. not my own contruct)

Comment: I give up helping, please read the docs and that error and post a new question if you're still having issues.

Comment: here @jake-n for you > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050116/symfony3-fosuserbundle-form-add-group-to-user